# Load a project template based on Wizard passed parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, wizard, visual-studio-extensions, project-template

I'm trying to extend Visual Studio to use tailored project templates.

While single project templates are alright, I'd like the user to  select a project and settings based on a wizard input.

So for example, he wants to create a project `foo`, but with 64 or 32 bit settings, and with or without `MFC` support, in which case, the project should load with those specific settings.

I can make individual project templates, and maybe include them in a bigger project template, but how do I make the `rootProject` load a specific `childProject`?

Comment: Did you try [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx)?

Comment: Ah but in a multi project template, from MSDN - "When a project based on a multi-project template is created from the New Project dialog box, every project in the template is added to the solution.". I don't want all the projects to load. If a user clicks on a Project, he should be presented with a wizard, which will let him input certain parameters, and a particular project based on those parameters ought to load. For example, a project with MFC support or or one without...

Comment: How about building the template xml based on your requirements? You already know the tags I guess.

Comment: Sorry? I didn't quite get that...

Comment: The project/solution template is an xml file. So may be you can create that xml in your code based on your requirement (which project to add based on user input) and then save that template. The full xml structure can be understood from existing template. Then you can modify on the fly wherever required.

Comment: is that the .vsTemplate XML file? I've seen it, but the standard one is very basic, with hardly any tags. Where would I get a tutorial on what I can edit in this file, for it to work the way I want?

Comment: If I edit the vstemplate file after the wizard input, how would it open as default the next time, offering the same options to the users which come by default?